# Why do we always assign Objective-C primitives?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, properties, primitive

It's common knowledge that we should use the attribute `(assign)` on primitive properties in Objective-C, yet I've never had a clear explanation as to why we do this.

consider

```
[myObject setIntProperty:22];
```

for class `myObject` that has a `@property (nonatomic, assign) int intProperty;`

My imagination says we would be assigning `intProperty` a pointer to stack memory that holds the value 22. So since that pointer has to live on for our property to have any value, does this mean that every primitive has an unlimited lifetime in stack memory?

Some more code to illustrate what I don't understand:

MyObject.h ----

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) int myInt;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString* myString;
@end
```

OtherFile.m ----

```
-(void) doSomething
{
   int x = 22;
   NSString* str = @"something";

   MyObject* obj = [[MyObject alloc] init];

   obj.myInt = x;
   obj.myString = str;

   [self doSomethingInOtherFunctionWith:obj];
}
```

Now once the `doSomething` function has completed and moved on, the assigned string myString now points to nothing, since it shared a pointer with the function's local `str,` which is destroyed after the function runs. But myInt remains as 22.

I understand that this is the way it works, being passed by value, and I do not question HOW it works, just WHY. Doesn't an int have to be a pointer at some level?

Comment: Objects are on the heap, so also their ivars are on the heap. The reason of using assign is that they're not objects, so it hasn't sense to retain or copy them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do we always assign Objective-C primitives?

Because we can't `retain` or `copy` them - that's for Objective-C objects only.

> My imagination says we would be assigning intProperty a pointer to stack memory

No, not really. We are assigning an `int` to it. Of course, internally, the instance variable is implemented as a pointer-to-int into the `myObject` object, with some offset added (described by the instance variable layout of the class).

But if by "stack variable", you mean "objects [that's the C terminology for variables] with automatic storage duration", then no. Objective-C objects are usually allocated dynamically (maybe "on the heap", but that's really irrelevant), and live as long as they are not deallocated, i. e. until their reference count reaches zero. Then they are deallocated, destroyed, and all of their instance variables (which back the corresponding `@property`es) are invalidated as well.

Comment: You're still here! :) What throws me off is that if, inside a function, I assign an object to a property of a different class, that property would point to nothing if I didn't retain it (because that object was locally scoped to the function). Yet, primitives seem to evade this scoping issue because if I create an int inside a function and assign it to a property, it lives on even though it was a local variable, and was never retained.

Comment: @user Please demonstrate your questions with some code. What you've written doesn't unfortunately make sense to me.

Comment: Now explain the downvote for which I see absolutely **no justification at all.**

Comment: I posted some code but I think I'm beginning to understand, and I see why this question might be confusing for people who really know whats going on under the hood. Is assigning a primitive essentially just copying whatever value it's given, as opposed to sharing a pointer?

Comment: @user Yes it is. In C, assignment generally means "copying memory", although there are quite a few exceptions (signed integers' sign extension process, not copied padding bytes in a struct, etc. but they don't apply here at first glance.)

Comment: Alright, that makes more sense. I guess I was thinking of a primitive as more of an object pointer than a disposable container for bits.